# Ubuntu 13.04 booting problem

Tags: installation, boot, grub2, 13.04

I have a Dell Inspiron 3521 laptop, Core i3 with 4GB RAM, and a 500 GB hard drive.

I tried to install Ubuntu 13.04 from a USB, alongside Windows 7. Everything went fine and it said restart now to finish. I restarted the laptop and only Windows shows up,and more than 100 GB of the HDD is gone. Please can someone help me get Ubuntu booting?

Comment: Did you install the bootloader during instillation?

Comment: @DaboRoss How can you not install a bootloader?

Comment: @Alvar I might be confusing with the other distros, but I am pretty sure there is an option to install without overriding the bootloader

Answer (score 0):

[Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) might help you.Take ubuntu live cd and install boot-repair it fixes most dual
boot problems.